The form of the tensor product of homomorphisms
I learn from Dummit Foute now and here.Let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be right modules and let $N_1$ and $N_2$ be left modules, then suppose  $\phi : M_1 \rightarrow M_2$ and $\psi : N_1 \rightarrow N_2$ are $R$-module homomorphisms. Then we can define tensor product of two homomorphisms. From the universal property of tensor product (in fact $R$-balanced map from $ M_1 \times N_1$ to $M_2 \otimes_R N_2$), we conclude that there is a unique group homomorphism maps  $M_1 \otimes_R N_1$ to  $M_2 \otimes_R N_2$. I am confused about why this homomorphism has the form of  $\phi \otimes \psi $.In the statement it doesn't give any explanation about the notation. Is it defined to be that or we can get that from previous knowledge?

Nobody claims that there is a unique group homomorphism. There is a unique group homomorphism that maps the pure tensors in a certain way. And that one we denote by $\phi \otimes \psi$. This is explained in more detail everywhere where tensor products are discussed. Please clarify your question, and cite the source you are working with. Please say exactly what you don't understand there. What you have done is basically to twist what has been written.

@MartinBrandenburg,I am new in module theory and I find many answers on this site and some PDFs which directly take this form for granted. So I cannot understand the reason well.

Here, the meaning is that if $\phi$ and $\psi$ are morphisms of $R$-modules, then the map $$\begin{array}{cccc}
\Psi: & M_1\times N_1 & \longrightarrow & M_2\otimes N_2 \\
    & (m_1,n_1) & \longmapsto & \phi(m_1)\otimes \psi(n_1) \end{array}$$
is $R$-bilinear. By universal property of tensor product, this yeilds a morphism of $R$-modules $\phi\otimes \psi : M_1\times N_1\longrightarrow M_2\otimes N_2$ which is given on pure tensors by $(\phi\otimes\psi)(m_1\otimes n_1)= \phi(m_1)\otimes \psi(n_1)$ (extension to non-pure tensors is done by linearity).
